# How to implement indexer and RemoveAt method to custom collection class?

Tags: c#, collections

I have class for connection mapping. I need to have access by index to `_connections`  and implement `RemoveAt(indx)` method.

Class:

```
public class ConnectionMapping<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _connections.Count;
        }
    }
    public void Add(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                connections = new HashSet<string>();
                _connections.Add(key, connections);
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Add(connectionId);
            }
        }
    }
    public void Remove(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Remove(connectionId);

                if (connections.Count == 0)
                {
                    _connections.Remove(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections(T key)
    {
        HashSet<string> connections;
        if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
        {
            return connections;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
_connections.RemoveAt(0); 
_connections[0].Value = _value, 
_connections[0].Key = _key;
```

How to modify class to achieve this goal?

Comment: You can't access a dictionary by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary doesn't maintain order so there is no consistent notion of an item at a given index. Consider inheriting from [`KeyedCollection<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class ConnectionMapping<T>
{
    private class Mapping
    {
        public T Key;
        public HashSet<string> Items;
    }

    private class ConnectionsCollection : KeyedCollection<T, Mapping>
    {
        protected override T GetKeyForItem(Mapping item)
        {
            return item.Key;
        }
    }

    private readonly ConnectionsCollection _connections = new ConnectionsCollection();

    /// Implementation of various collection methods, Add, RemoveAt, etc.

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        lock(_connections)
        {
            _connections.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to add some helper methods on the `ConnectionsCollection` for dictionary-like access (e.g. TryGetValue). The locking that you have currently is not sufficient. You would need to lock in `GetConnections` as well. Don't return the actual collection from there either, return a copy of the `connections`.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary doesn't keep any order of its elements and therefore there is no way to know which one to remove. You can use  `Remove(TKey key)` only.

Or you can use an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)

```
Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are accessible by the key or index.
```

`RemoveAt` is already implemented
[OrderedDictionary.RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.removeat.aspx)